# Locked out of Mac OS X Lion, but keyboard and mouse are not connecting

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth, mouse, screen-lock

I'm at the lock screen of Mac OS X Lion (not login, but the quick lock screen), and I know my password, but the keyboard and mouse are not connecting.  I am using an iMac that did have Bluetooth on the last time I was working on it.  I know that restarting the computer will probably help, but I have unsaved work on Xcode 4!  Thanks in advance.

Edit: it seems that Bluetooth is off for some reason on the Mac, as I cannot find it in a list of discoverable devices on my iPod.  Is there a way to restart Bluetooth from a USB device?  I was wondering if hooking up my iPod would help, but the Mac is locked and won't do anything!  If I could click the Switch User button...

Comment: Is Screen Sharing enabled which would allow you to use another Mac to log into your iMac and re-enable Bluetooth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove the batteries and then put then back.
If not then try USB Keyboard or Remote Desktop/VNC

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think you're understanding my question.  The keyboard and mouse are fine, but Bluetooth is off on the Mac, and I can't install any software or turn Bluetooth on without unlocking my account, which I need a keyboard to do.

Comment: @iphonedev46 I wonder if you know what USB and VNC is. That was a proposed means to log into your computer and hopefully see what is wrong. There is no hidden Bluetooth switch on the Mini itself.

Comment: I do know what USB and VNC are. I'm sorry if my previous comment was a little unclear. I was just trying to say that I can't turn VNC on through System Prefs while my Mac is locked. I don't own a USB keyboard, either, unfortunately.  Anyway, it seems that I have underestimated the usefulness of Lion's new 'Resume' feature, which saved my Xcode work (except for a few lines of code).  Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: A USB keyboard is the only real solution, so this answer is the solution.